# Potentiometer output voltage for inverting amplifier and non-inverting

Tags: operational-amplifier, potentiometer

[image: Potentiometer on inverting amplifier that is adjusted to 2V]

When setting the voltage input to 2V from potentiometer, why does it increase to 2.55V after the Vout of potentiometer is disconnected for an inverting amplifier? And remains the same voltage of 2V for an non-inverting amplifier?

Comment: It's just the simulator.  Reality doesn't work that way.

Comment: You  have set the pot to 51% of 5V and disconnected it from the 10K resistor. What do you expect the voltage to be?

Answer (score 1):

Find the Thevenin equivalent for the voltage source (the pot) and compare loading for inverting and non-inverting cases.

Note that the Thevenin resistance (as well as the voltage) is a function of pot wiper angle.

If the voltage is set exactly to 2V, the pot voltage when open should be 2.50V not 2.55, by the way.

Comment: How do you obtained the value of 2.5V when the voltage is set exactly to 2V? Thank you.

Comment: If the 10K pot is set in the middle, the equivalent is a 2.50V voltage source with 2.5K resistance. When loaded with 10K from the inverting amplifier the wiper voltage (ideally) is exactly 2V.

Comment: Did you use a voltage divider to obtain the 2.5V when pot is disconnect and 2V when pot is connected? Thank you.

Comment: And i thought 2.50V voltage source is a 5k resistance at the lower half of the pot when disconnect?

Comment: 2.5K source resistance when the 5V source is connected (and the pot wiper is in the center).

Answer (score 0):

For the inverting configuration both of the op amp's inputs are at nearly the same potential at ground potential and so the 10k resistor is in parallel with the lower half of the pot drawing extra current through the top half of the pot and lowering its output voltage from that voltage output when the pot is isolated from the 10k resistor.

For the non-inverting configuration the op amp's + input draws only a tiny current and so it doesn't affect the voltage at the pot output.

Comment: Can i say that it is due to the low input impedance of inverting amplifier and high input impedance of non-inverting amplifier which result to this output voltage?

Comment: Yes, that would be fine. The difference in input impedance between the two amplifier's results in different currents being drawn out of the pot which in turn results in a large voltage drop at the pot's output for the inverting amp and a small voltage drop at the pot's output for the non-inverting amp.

Comment: Noted. Thank you.